# AngularJS Quicksand

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, quicksand

Is there any way to implement jQuery's [Quicksand plugin](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) in Angular? Perhaps there is an implementation but I can't seem to find it.

Perhaps a strategy to do it would help me because quicksand takes a list and then receives as a parameter the new list, but with Angular's way of re-rendering data I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: as with any other DOM manipulation plugin, need to initialize it within an angular directive. Wrap your code in `$timeout` if angular will be creating the `LI` elements such as with `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I implemented something similar using a masonry directive + ng-animate for enter/leave animations, here's a CSS animation only demo (with chrome vendor prefixed CSS):

http://jsfiddle.net/g/3SH7a/

The directive:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive("masonry", function () {
    var NGREPEAT_SOURCE_RE = '<!-- ngRepeat: ((.*) in ((.*?)( track by (.*))?)) -->';
    return {
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            // auto add animation to brick element
            var animation = attrs.ngAnimate || "'masonry'";
            var $brick = element.children();
            $brick.attr("ng-animate", animation);

            // generate item selector (exclude leaving items)
            var type = $brick.prop('tagName');
            var itemSelector = type+":not([class$='-leave-active'])";

            return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var options = angular.extend({
                    itemSelector: itemSelector
                }, attrs.masonry);

                // try to infer model from ngRepeat
                if (!options.model) { 
                    var ngRepeatMatch = element.html().match(NGREPEAT_SOURCE_RE);
                    if (ngRepeatMatch) {
                        options.model = ngRepeatMatch[4];
                    }
                }

                // initial animation
                element.addClass('masonry');

                // Wait inside directives to render
                setTimeout(function () {
                    element.masonry(options);

                    element.on("$destroy", function () {
                        element.masonry('destroy')
                    });

                    if (options.model) {
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            scope.$watchCollection(options.model, function (_new, _old) {
                                if(_new == _old) return;

                                // Wait inside directives to render
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    element.masonry("reload");
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            };
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: That is pretty slick. I'm working with a more complex example where there are LI's inside of the container (which is also an LI) and there is a problem with the animation being applied to all descendants. My fix was to change   `var itemSelector = type+":not([class$='-leave-active'])";` to `var itemSelector = '.masonry > ' + type + ":not([class$='-leave-active'])";`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [directive](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/angularjs-directives-and-the-computer-science-of-javascript.html) to do this.

So with just jQuery, you'd have:

**JS**

```
$('#source').quicksand( $('#destination li') );
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="source">
  <li data-id="iphone">iOS</li>
  <li data-id="android">Android</li>
  <li data-id="winmo">Windows Phone 7</li>
</ul>

<ul id="destination" class="hidden">
  <li data-id="macosx">Mac OS X</li>
  <li data-id="macos9">Mac OS 9</li>
  <li data-id="iphone">iOS</li>
</ul>
```

With Angular you could do:

**JS**

```
yourApp.directive('jqQuicksand', function(){
    var linkFn = function(scope,element,attrs){
        // element here = $(this)
        // bind your plugin or events (click, hover etc.) here
        element.quicksand( $(attrs.jqQuicksand) );
    }

    return {
        restrict:'A',
        scope: {},
        link: linkFn
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul data-jq-quicksand="#destination li" id="source">
  <li data-id="iphone">iOS</li>
  <li data-id="android">Android</li>
  <li data-id="winmo">Windows Phone 7</li>
</ul>

<ul id="destination" class="hidden">
  <li data-id="macosx">Mac OS X</li>
  <li data-id="macos9">Mac OS 9</li>
  <li data-id="iphone">iOS</li>
</ul>
```

Note, this is untested but should be ok.