# iCheck plugin with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, angularjs, radio-button

There's an awesome plugin for checkboxes and radio buttons customization (seems to be a best one for that).

https://github.com/damirfoy/iCheck

How do I connect it with [Angular.js](http://angularjs.org/)?

I'm not too familiar with Angular. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use iCheck, or pretty much any jQuery plugin with Angular.

The easiest way would be to use the [jQuery Passthrough feature of AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/jq) or to write your own Angular directive to wrap a jQuery feature or plugin.

Ex. of wrapping jQuery plugin call in a directive:

[AngularJS Quicksand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004569/angularjs-quicksand/16119761#16119761)

[How do I force jQuery to "listen" for, and activate plugins on, future AngularJS ng-repeat elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117397/how-do-i-force-jquery-to-listen-for-and-activate-plugins-on-future-angularjs/16118053#16118053)

Since you are new to Angular, I suggest you check out the videos over on http://egghead.io. They are an excellent leeway in the AngularJS world. Plus there's a hand-full of videos showcasing the ins and outs of directives .